# How to compare number of commas in bash argument with those in text file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a text file containing:

```
1,2,3
```

I have a script insert that takes a parameter, and I want to compare the number of commas in that parameter to the number in the textfile.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if [ ((grep -c "," "$1/$2.txt")) -gt ((grep -c "," "$3")) ] | [ ((grep -c "," "$1/$2.txt")) -lt ((grep -c "," "$3")) ]; 
      then echo "yes"
```

$1/$2.txt is the directory for the text file

I know I'm doing this wrong but have no idea how to get that count of commas, since -c returns the number of lines. And I'm not sure about half of the syntax. Should I be using sed instead? It would be great to hear any suggestions...

Comment: What are `$1` and `$2`? Directory and filename?

Comment: Hi sorry yes I forgot to mention that

Comment: Edited it now, so i might run ./script folder filename how,many,commas

Comment: Are these really one-line files?

Comment: Ultimately no but I will always be testing the number of commas against the first line

Comment: When posting a question pertaining to `bash`, please do not include `sh` (which relates to POSIX shell). Features available in bash do not exist in POSIX shell. If on the other hand, you want a POSIX shell compliant answer, then don't include bash. (it just helps keep the tags straight)

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything *except* the commas, then count the number of characters.

```
commas () {
    echo "$1" | tr -cd , | wc -m
}
```

You can then pass the first line of the file and your other parameter to the function:

```
IFS= read -r l < "$1/$2.txt"
if [[ $(commas "$l") -lt $(commas "$3") ]]; then
```

Comment: @TylerMarshall That's... way better. Thanks. There's also `l1=1,2,3; l2=${l1//[^,]}`, after which you can use `${#l2}` to get the count as well, which is more verbose but also more efficient than a command substitution to run `commas`.

Comment: Thanks for this guys, however there's still a lot I don't quite understand. What does the -cd do in tr? I've read the man page but can't understand it... I get that it's taking out anything that isn't the comma, allowing wc to count it, but how is it doing that?

Comment: tr usually **TR**anslates characters.  Giving it the `-d` option will make tr **D**elete characters. To tell it which characters to delete, we give it a command line arg of all the characters. If we ran `tr -d ,` that would do the opposite of what we want:  it would delete all commas instead of preserve them.  That's what the `-c` is for. `-c` says to use the **C**omplement of the set of characters we gave it.  We gave it the comma, so the complement of that is every character except the comma. In summary, `tr -dc ,` will **D**elete all characters in the **C**omplement of the set `,`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from *chepner*, a combination of `grep` and `wc` will also accomplish this:

```
commas () {
    head -1 "$1" |grep -o , |wc -l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only want to compare the number of commas, you can use

```
if [ "$(tr -cd "," < "$1"/"$2")" = "$(tr -cd , < "$3")" ]; then
   echo yes
fi
```

EDIT:
I thought `$3` was another file. When it is a string, you can use

```
if [ "$(tr -cd "," < "$1"/"$2")" = "$(tr -cd , <<< "$3")" ]; then
   echo yes
fi
```

Comment: `$3` is the actual data to compare against, not another file name.